# Can I use the output as a param in #define

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am working on a backward compatibility project and so, I need to re-define things without messing with old code. I want to use the output as one of the params in a `#define`.
For example : my old code contains

```
#define OPERATION(y) ...
```

and we used it

```
x = OPERATION(y);
```

in the new code we have:

```
#define OPERATION_NEW(y,x) ...
```

and we use it like:

```
x = OPERATION_NEW(y,x);
```

**notice that now x is a result and a param.**

I want to be able to do the next:

```
#define OPERATION(y) OPERATION_NEW(y,__output__)
```

**(I want to be able to get the output as a param and use it in the define...)**

is it possible ? and if so, how ? if not , is there a solution for this situation ? I have tones of old code that have the OPERATION(y) and want to re-direct it to OPERATION_NEW(y,x) -while keeping in mind that x must be the output...

Comment: I guess you mean you use `OPERATION_NEW` as `x = OPERATION_NEW(x,y);`

Comment: You want to the the output _from what_?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to overload `operator=` of `x` ?

Comment: This may be one of those times where you're trying to solve the *wrong problem*. Could you provide more context as to the use of these macros (including affected types and as much call-context as possible)?

Comment: in the old code we use one y (OPERATION(y)) but in the new code we need to use the output as well (OPERATION_NEW(y,x) - x is the output). so in order to re-direct OPERATION in old code to OPERATION_NEW I need the output in the define. is there another solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. There's no such thing as an "output" for a macro. In this particular case, `OPERATION(y)` is a macro which expands to an expression. That expression is subsequently assigned to `x`.

But the preprocessor handles just the macro, not the assignment. It doesn't know or care about the previous token. The compiler only sees the assignment and the expressions on both sides, not the macro. Neither has a complete picture.

Comment: I thought that if macro can know the all the args (with the keyword "args..."), maybe we can somehow get the output as well...apparently not...any thoughts on how to solve it ?

Comment: @yehudahs: as I said, there IS no "output". The preprocessor first works on `x`, sees that it's not a macro, and skips it. It then sees `=`, sees that it's not a macro, and skips it. When it's come to `OPERATION`, it does know that's a macro, but has already forgotten both tokens `x` and `=`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the `x` argument in `OPERATION_NEW` is being *assigned to*. However, this is not possible to do if you also should "return" it from the macro, you have to resort to functions:

```
template<class T, class U>
T operation_new(U y)
{
    T dummy;
    return OPERATION_NEW(y, dummy);
}

#define OPERATION(y) operation_new(y)
```

The above solution is C++, doing a pure C version is basically the same, but you use fixed types in place of the template parameters `T` and `U`.

Comment: the OPERATION_NEW is an intrinsic (for the compiler)- this intrinsic is "same res" - gets the output as an input as well.

Comment: I don't think this compiles. `T` is a non-deducable template parameter of `operation_new`, which means that the definition of `OPERATION(y)` should provide it.

Answer (score 0):

In `x = OPERATION(y,x);` `OPERATION` is processed by the preprocessor and substitutes text. Then `x = <whatever was substituted>` is compiled by the compiler. The first step has *no knowledge* of the argument to the left of the assignment operator.

But if I understand right, let's say we have:

`#define OPERATION_NEW(y,x) do_foo(y, x);`

So you just change that to:

`#define OPERATION_NEW(y,x) x = do_foo(y, x);`

And instead of using assignment you pass the source/destination `x` into the macro as a parameter. Alternately edit your question with the real problem you're trying to solve.